# How do I create links to an artist, track or album in a Spotify App as described in the App Guidelines?

Tags: spotify

[Point 16. of the app design guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/02_app-design-guidelines.html) describes how links to artists, tracks or albums should look like but I can't find a place that tells how one can create such a link with HTML/CSS and/or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is so simple... It's the player view we're talking about here. See this example:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/models");
var views = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/api/views");

$(document).ready(function()
{
    new models.Album.fromURI("spotify:album:7auFBtmCGcTn7ElPelMLPn", function(ctx)
    {
        var player = new views.Player();
        player.context = ctx;

        $("#my-album-player").append(player.node);
    });
});
```

Thanks to [ikenndac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29005/ikenndac) who sent me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="spotify:album:65YwWxg4kkvzsD91hvels1">Horse Of a Different Color</a>
```

The client will be smart enough to do the right thing. You can get these URIs from `Track`, `Artist`, `Album` and `Playlist` objects in the API.

Comment: That was also my first guess but is not working as I want it to. This is just showing a link to an album. Sure, you can already drag this arround but what I want and need is the widget as shown in point 16 with the album cover and the play button in front of it.

Comment: Aha, you asked how to make a link, not a widget ;-). You probably need a Player view (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/ca28d10757.html), or the Apps Tutorial might help you out: https://github.com/spotify/apps-tutorial